# how can i run this program when clicking the button in java?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Client extends JPanel {

    public static void main( String[] args) {

        clients application;

        if (args.length == 0)
            application = new clients("");
        else
            application = new clients(args[0]);
            application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

    }
}
```

I have a java program which consists of swing buttons,When i click on a button i need this program to be executed.How to do?i have tried all possible cases.

Comment: What program do you want to be executed when you click a button from your main program?

Comment: You want it to run in a separate process or within the same JVM?

Comment: The [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) is your best friend.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `main` method here.
If you want to have a separate thread for running some code - just create thread and run it.